# TypeError: fetch failed while fetching in NextJS 13

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data on NextJS 13 server side component from my local server using built-in fetch, but recieving this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (D:\next\shop-app\front\shop-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:26669)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

My fetching function:

```
async function getProducts(id:number) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.LOCAL_SERVER}/api/products/category/${id}`);
    const products = await res.json();
    return Object.values(products) as ProductItem[];
}
```

.env file:

```
LOCAL_SERVER=https://localhost:7187
```

Same request works from swagger, curl, or browser's console. I searched all over the web, but neither downgrading Node.js version nor using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

I'm a beginner, so take this with a huge pinch of salt.

I think currently, during build, NEXTJS is trying to make the fetch and your app is offline (being built) so it can't access that URL(to itself) thus it fails.

I'm unsure why changing the URL helped for some in previous versions, i found, like you, that that fix (from localhost to 127.0.0.1) no longer works.

I think if you add this line:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
```

then inside your function add a call to Cookies (we won't use it, but we just trick `NextJS` into making the page dynamic *i think*)

```js
const cookieStore = cookies()
```

I think it then causes the page to be dynamic, which i THINK at build time means it doesn't try to make the fetch call? I could be wrong.

Its not ideal, but it got my site working.

I'm trying to figure out, why my site isn't working, even though my fetch(to itself) has 'no store'. I thought this would make the page dynamic, seems not?

```js
var results = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/filter?${searchParmsObj.toString()}`, {
        method: "GET",
        **cache: "no-store",**
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
```

I THOUGHT that nextJS would see no-store, and build a dynamic page, but it doesn't seem to.

I realise this doesn't fully solve your problem, but its a workaround for now and may help others figure out the actual cause of the issue.

It does seem logical that if our website, is trying to access itself, as build time, it would fail since it would be offline.
However I thought no-cache in my fetch would achieve the same as using 'cookies' here to make the page dynamic.

I remain confused :)